# R Winsorize Returning NaN

Tags: r

I have 4 columns of data and am using the winsorize function in R to winsorize each of the columns. However, when I winsorize one of the columns (called toocheap), by doing 
    `winsorize(pricing0.12$toocheap)`

I get all NaN values returned. This does not happen when I do the same with the other 3 columns. And when I load it from the .csv the toocheap columns looks the exact same as the other columns, albeit with different values of course. Any idea what is happening here?

My dataframe which I'm loading using read_csv from a csv file that I'm viewing in Excel looks like this:

```
structure(list(toocheap = c(800, 500, 500, 500, 500, 400), cheap = c(900, 
900, 875, 800, 800, 600), expensive = c(1000, 975, 950, 900, 
900, 800), tooexpensive = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: what class are the different vectors? Also please include a sample of your data (eg pasting the output of `dput(head(pricing0.12))` into your question) so we can help you

Comment: edited my post to add this. another thing that may be important is that the toocheap column has more repeating values at the low end than the others, is this causing the issue?

Comment: Try using `Winsorize` from  package `DescTools`. This should work.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!